# PyDev: How to get a call heirarchy? How to jump to a declaration?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am working on a large project that has much code from both Java and Python ( all OO ).   The code is organized as many Eclipse plugins joined together as one piece of software.

When I am in Java code Eclipse provides the very convenient option of jumping to the declaration of the artifact hightlighted.  It also provides the very convenient option of showing me the call hierarchy of whatever method definition I have high lighted.

I don't see such conveniences when I am in Python files/projects.

Is there something similar in PyDev or another plugin I can install to get that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Use `F3` or `Ctrl+Click` to jump to declaration (there's no call hierarchy in the same way that JDT has).

I really recommend you take a look at http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_navigate_code.html if you still haven't as it provides more info on how to navigate the code with PyDev (it's actually a part of the Getting started manual: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html, which you're advised to read to make sure you configure what's needed in PyDev properly).